# multipledispatch ModuleNotFoundError running from command-line

Tags: python, pip, locust, modulenotfounderror, multiple-dispatch

Running a `locust` ([locust.io](https://locust.io)) script from the command line.

`locust` calls `main.py` which has the following imports:

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
from StreamLoader.stream_generator import *    # thought this brings in everything
```

`Packer.py` has these imports:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch
from PackedItem import PackedItem
```

`StreamGenerator.py` has:

```
import hashlib
from StreamLoader.Packer import Packer
from aes_encryption import AesEncryption
```

I used `pip` to install `multipledispatch` and when I run from within PyCharm it works fine, but from the command line I get the following.

```
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\engine_load_tester_locust\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from StreamLoader.stream_generator import *
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\StreamLoader\stream_generator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from StreamLoader.Packer import Packer
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\StreamLoader\Packer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from multipledispatch import dispatch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multipledispatch'
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Add directories to the PYTHONPATH environment variable
2. Add empty `__init__.py` files in each package

This all seems unnecessary if I actually `pip install`ed the module, though.

---

Answer below caused me to no longer see the error with `multipledispatch`.  However, I now see a missing module error:

```
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\engine_load_tester_locust\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from StreamLoader.stream_generator import *
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\StreamLoader\stream_generator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Packer import Packer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Packer'
```

For clarity, I am running the code from `locust` which calls the Python code as depicted here.  [Moderators - this question is getting quite long.  Is that all right?]

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyCharm uses the virtual environment automatically but when you run from the command line the virtual environment isn't turned on.

Just follow the steps:

1. `cd your_working_directory`
2. `environment_name/Scripts/activate` if on `Windows` where `environment_name`  is the name of the PyCharm virtual environment

Or `environment_name/bin/activate` if on `MacOS`

-------------EDIT------------------------
To answer the new question, try using `pip freeze` then see which packages are installed. Then install any dependencies which you want which are missing.

Comment: that advice was helpful; resolved the issue with ```multipledispatch``` but another one cropped up.  I'll post it in the original post so it's easier to read.

Comment: Should I accept this answer and create a new question?

Comment: Sure you can accept this. I'll review your new question. The question is getting harder to read, so if you could make a new question that would be great.