# locust run showing ModuleNotFound for Python module

Tags: python, pycharm, dependencies, locust, modulenotfounderror

Follow-up from earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523535/multipledispatch-modulenotfounderror-running-from-command-line)

Running a `locust` ([locust.io](https://locust.io)) script from the command line.

`locust` calls `main.py` which has the following imports:

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
from StreamLoader.stream_generator import *    # thought this brings in everything
```

`Packer.py` has these imports:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch
from PackedItem import PackedItem
```

`StreamGenerator.py` has:

```
import hashlib
from StreamLoader.Packer import Packer
from aes_encryption import AesEncryption
```

I now see a missing module error:

```
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\engine_load_tester_locust\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from StreamLoader.stream_generator import *
  File "C:\Users\guyl\PycharmProjects\engine-load-tests\StreamLoader\stream_generator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Packer import Packer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Packer'
```

For clarity, I am running the code from `locust` which calls the Python code as depicted here.

[image]

Here's the file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed periods (full stops) before the package names in the `import` statements.

I then was able to run the `locust` script from within PyCharm.

Running from the DOS shell, I was able to accomplish the same by first running

```
<project directory>\venv\Scripts\activate
```